# Browsers and Bluetooth Headphones in KDE

Tags: bluetooth, kde-plasma

My Bluetooth headphones work great with non-browser apps.  Zoom, Skype, and VLC are all working fine.

In order to get this working, I went into System Settings > Device Preference > Audio Playback and put the Bluetooth headphones above the Built-In Audio option.

Unfortuantely, when I try to use them with a web browser, the sound just comes through the computer's speaker.  This happens with both Firefox and Chrome.  I tested on BigBlueButton, Jitsi, and Google Play Music.

How can I fix the playback from the browsers so that it uses the headphones?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using Pulse Audio Volume Control.

First, I had to start some audio playing on the browser I wanted to use with my headphones.  (I used Google Play Music, but anything should work.)  Then I ran Pulse Audio Volume Control and in the Playback tab, it included an entry for Firefox.

I clicked on the box to the right of "on", which had the Built-In Audio option.  That brought up a drop-down menu, and I chose the headphones I wanted to use.

This choice persists even when playback stops on that browser.  I can close the audio-playing tab, then start something else, and it still comes back over the headphones.  (I expect I'll have to follow these steps again if the headphones disconnect.)

This setting does not persist across multiple browsers.  After setting it up for Firefox, I had to set it up again separately for Chrome (using the same process).

Comment: This does not seem to be a good solution.  Now the mic on my headphones doesn't work at all.

Comment: Strangely enough - I don't see such option at all ... this is what I get in the volume control modal - https://i.postimg.cc/qRv1FkZp/image.png ... Could it be that you have installed something else as well?

Comment: @peshohristov I don't recall.  I just gave up on getting my bluetooth headphones to work with my laptop.

Comment: OK ... I'll keep digging and will post a solution if I find one :)